# How to use html5 video player?

Tags: html, html5-video

how to use html5 video player? 
If have idea about setup html5 video player with custom controls.

Answer (score 0):

Please visit given below link.

1. http://www.webdesign-flash.ro/p/uvp/modern-white.html#/?playlistId=0&videoId=0
2. http://www.cincopa.com/media-platform/start.aspx

Comment: you can also check another links http://malsup.com/jquery/media/video.html, http://html5video.org/wiki/OSM_HTML5_Video_Player

Comment: more links alos http://www.codebasehero.com/2011/07/html5-video-player/, 
http://www.videoplayerhtml5.com/